# Elasticseach sort only the result by date field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an elasticsearch index where I want to retrieve 10 records by relevance score and then sort only those 10 results by a date field. But when I use the sort option below I am not getting desirable results & the results are not sorted by date in ascending order too. Any suggestion?

```
            "sort": [
                    { "_score": { "order": "desc" }},
                    { "startTime":   { "order": "desc" }}
                ]
```

Comment: whats the type of `startTime`? can i see your index mapping please?

Comment: If `startTime` is not date datatype sorting won't work.

Comment: startTime is of type 'date'